# Where is my homepage code and the reference to a static block?

Tags: static-block

My cms - home page has only this...

[image]

I notice others often have something more akin to a normal looking page structure. I have a theme installed and I've found both of the files being pointed to here.

The reason I would like to know is that I have some images which were created in a static block being displayed in the left hand column of the home page. I can find no reference to the static block in either of the two files. So how does magento know to display the static block? I would like to know as I want to add the same kind of behavior to other pages.

Would appreciate any assistance

When I click on design the options are empty...

[image]

I don't see the references you refer to. Appreciate your help.

UPDATE

Here is the screenshot of the homepage, thanks

[image]

Comment: Can you also add your home page screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the `Content` tab of your CMS homepage. Try looking at `Design` tab of that page. The sidebar blocks can be defined there.

For right sidebar

```
<reference name="right">
    some block code
</reference>
```

For left sidebar

```
<reference name="left">
    some block code
</reference>
```